# Add a padding function in a tableView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I would like to adjust this function (that was created originally for a `collectionView`)

```
 let place = places[indexPath.row]
        let annotationPadding = CGFloat(5)

        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        let commentHeight = place.heightForComment(font, width: width)

        let height = annotationPadding + commentHeight + annotationPadding

        return height
```

So I can add it in   `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { }` in my `tableView`, how can I do? (My problem is that `CGFloat` do not accept `width`)

Comment: create width as local variable such as var width: CGFloat = 0 and set it when you will have a width.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `heightForComment` for the collection view takes the width of the collection view cell, you can pass in the width of the table view, since table view cells are as wide as their containing table view:

```
let commentHeight = place.heightForComment(font, width: tableView.bounds.size.width)
```

If there is additional leading or trailing margins for the comment in the table view, you can subtract that from the table view width:

```
let commentHeight = place.heightForComment(font, width: tableView.bounds.size.width - (20 * 2)) // 20 points margin on left and right
```